# Need help with figuring out how to play a weird part in the piece. The bass clef is weird

Tags: chords

When looking at this part of the music, I saw the part in the bass clef and I didn't know how to play, it seems like I need 3 hands to play this part of the piece so I didn't know what to do. Please give some pointers. Thanks!

[image]